# Calculating the p-value of two independent counts?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, count-data, poisson-process

**My simple experiment:**

Two equally-sized patches of the night sky are observed:

- Patch A contains $100$ stars
- Patch B contains $110$ stars

My **null hypothesis** is that stars are randomly distributed in the sky. The random distribution means that there will be some natural variation from patch to patch.

**My question:**

1. How is the **p-value** (or at the very least, a **test statistic**) calculated for rejecting the null hypothesis that there is no significant difference between the two patches of sky?